# Creating realistic procedural wall plaster texture

Tags: materials, node-editor

How do I make a simple procedural texture to get a result similar to this?

In real life its a traditional wall plaster that its not smooth.

[image]

It looks like this in real life.

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe post real life example with a closer view?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Musgrave procedural noise node as displacement texture for a very simple plaster like surface. You can change the node settings to control how rough and detailed the plaster would be.

[image]